# Как сделать так, чтобы текстовые поля отображались предварительно заполненным в зависимости от раскрывающегося меню?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Начну с того, что я новичок в кодировании, так что я нахожу это очень трудно, и я задал несколько вопросов, в основном потому, что я действительно застрял, поэтому вся помощь очень ценится

Как сделать так, чтобы текстовые поля отображались предварительно заполненным в зависимости от раскрывающегося меню (примеры в картинках)?

Код раскрывающегося меню

```
<div class="box catalog__head-row">
    <span class="catalog__label">Команда:</span>
    @{
        var lst = ViewData["Commands"] as List<SelectListItem>;
        var selectedName = ViewData["Select_Command_Id"] != null ? lst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == ViewData["Select_Command_Id"].ToString())?.Text : "";
     }
     <div class="pseudoselect catalog__select">
         @Html.Hidden("Command_id", ViewData["Select_Command_Id"], new { @class = "id_command" })
         <input type="text" class="pseudoselect__input" placeholder="Выбрать из списка" value="@selectedName">
         <div class="pseudoselect__dropdown custom-scroll">
             <div class="pseudoselect__current">@selectedName</div>
             <div class="pseudoselect__list">
                 @foreach (var data in lst)
                 {
                     <li data-id_command="@data.Value">@data.Text</li>
                 }
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     @Html.TextBox("Str_filter", "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "catalog__input", type = "search", placeholder = "Поиск по таблице", id = "findField" })
</div>
```

Пример Drop down menu
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример с одним TextField

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример с тремя TextField

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `так что я нахожу это очень трудно` вы текст вопроса через гугл переводчик писали что ли?

Comment: На мой взгляд ни c#, ни asp.net здесь не причём, т.к. манипуляции с DOM реализуются на JS. Со стороны сервера Вы, скорее всего, можете получить разметку или данные. Вам необходимо определить взаимосвязь между данными, и в зависимости от выбранного элемента отображать и скрывать элементы на странице. На чистом JS и HTML можно было-бы подсказать, но у Вас для раскрывающихся списков используется какая-то сторонняя библиотека.

Comment: Html код, что вы привели, вы его сами руками писали?

Comment: Какие текстовые поля вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Также хотелось бы ваши попытки, мысли, идеи тоже увидеть. Кусок html и три скриншота - это выглядит как ваша задача, но не тянет на вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 текстовые поля для ввода данных, например «сумма кредита (в копейках)»

Comment: я знаю, что такое текстовое поле. Я не понял, как это связано с вашим вопросом

Comment: @tym32167 я пытался реализовать их через объект Command, а именно передать объект во View и использовать в drop down menu так, как у него есть параметры которые используются в полях для ввода текстов например надпись для label «сумма кредита (в копейках)» и она является лишь частью класса Command. Ссылка на API -  http://46.254.21.245:98/commands/types?token=4Fgdujwkskd4DFGHsFfF456Gd

Comment: Я вам говорю, что ваша задача не ясна. Я не понимаю ваши скрины. Я не понимаю, почему в одном случае у вас нет полей, в другом 1 поле, в третьем 3 поля. Как и что вы реализовать пытались тоже не ясно, так как не понятна ваша задача.

Comment: @XelaNimed я пытался определить взаимосвязь между данными на сторонне сервера, используя c# и razor, чтобы отображать и скрывать элементы, но нужно ещё использовать данные из класса command для отображения label и предварительного заполнения полей так, как выбранный пункт из drop down menu является частью класса command.

Comment: @tym32167 это то что я пытаюсь реализовать, поля привязаны к классу command, а тот в свою очередь берет данные из API Json ссылку я вам отправил, а взаимосвязь между полями берётся из того, есть ли parameter_name1, или там null и в зависимости от этого мы решаем отображать ли текстовое поле или нет. А параметра всего три, поэтому и поля три. Вся эта конструкция зависит от drop down menu и является частью класса command.

Comment: то есть вам надо: 1) получить json из API, 2) проверить поля в нем на null 3) Для non-nul полей нарисовать текстбоксы. Это все можно сделать на javascript (в браузере) или на C# (в бекенде)

Comment: по большому счету, вам надо решить, вы в браузере или на сервере будете выполнять эту логику и уже пясать от этого. Например, можно ваш код засунуть в форму и отправлять на сервер если юзер что то выбрал в выкидушке. А можно всю логику прописать на JS и выполнить на клиенте

Comment: @tym32167 я пытался сделать на сервере, но ничего не получилось

Comment: добавьте код, что вы пытались, в вопрос и укажите, что именно не получилось

Comment: Ок, у вас есть терминал и команды с определёнными параметрами, которые Вы можете на нём выполнить. В этом случае, почему бы не отправлять id команды на сервер, который в свою очередь возвращал бы ответ в виде HTML как частичного представления (тут могу в термине ошибиться)? Другими словами: пользователь выбирает команду > id команды отправляется на сервер по AJAX > ответ сервера "вставляется" в определённое место на странице. Либо сразу на сервере формируйте все возможные варианты, но скрывайте и показывайте их по мере необходимости в зависимости от выбранной комманды.